# Copying the file from docker container to host when we are running the docker image

Tags: file, docker

I want to copy one file from a Docker container to localhost.

I know the command is

```
docker cp <container id>:<container path> <host path>
```

but this command will only work when you are outside the container.

I want to copy the file from Docker container while its image is being run: what would I can include in an entry point script which copies the file from the Docker container to the host machine?

Comment: You can mount folder/directory in between Docker container and host machine, while running Docker container just add this parameter -v /{local}/{path}:/{container}/{path}. Once you mounted you can share the same file in between host and Docker container, this will be similar to copy from any end.

Comment: Thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

Docker container instances are being isolated from the docker hosts. Container instances are not supposed to access data on the docker hosts. So that's why only the opposite direction is supposed to work.